# Query list of layers an run code on each layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I want to query all opened layers in my QGIS project and then run an algorithm on each of the opened layers.

```
layers_list = []
layers_list = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
name_field = 'Admin_name'

for layer in layers_list:
   name = [f[name_field] for f in layers_list.getFeatures()[0]
   .... do something smart ....
```

It always throws me an error: 'dict_value' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

I m aware that the list only contains the names of the opened layers an no direct pointer to that layer - but how can i achieve that my `for`- loop goes through all the layers?

Comment: shouldn't `layers_list.getFeatures()[0]` be `layer.getFeatures()[0]`?

Comment: and I think `layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()` should be `layers_list = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()`

Comment: in the first for loop, it should be then `for layer in layers_list:` as well, right?

Comment: no your variable is `layers_list` so the loop line is correct

Comment: okay i corrected the code, but the error stays the same, the list of layers is just a list containing strings and no actual pointer to the layer - or am i getting this concept wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bellow, following @IanTurton comments, is a right way to do this :

```
layers_list = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
name_field = "Admin_name"

for lyr in layers_list:
    name_data = [f[name_field] for f in lyr.getFeatures()]
    # .... do something smart ....
```

---

*Explanations*

`QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()` list all layers (vector and raster) in the current QGIS project, so, `layers_list` contains a list of <kbd>QgsMapLayer</kbd>.

In the `for` loop, we affect `lyr` an item at a time for each item in the `layers_list`, so, `lyr` is a project <kbd>QgsMapLayer</kbd> at each loop.

`QgsMapLayer.getFeatures()` gets all the features of a layer, and we can access to each `"Admin_name"` values with `f["Admin_name"]` if `f` is the current <kbd>QgsFeature</kbd> in the comprehension list loop.

p.s. : yes, the [QGIS cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) is your friend !

Comment: uff, that does the trick, but only after i changed `layer` to `lyr` in the `for` loop. i guess i need to read the cookbook further.. thanks alot @J.Monticolo and @Ian Turton